# Are there any good alternative to Hibernate Tools in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, plugins

I can't believe that the only production-ready hibernate plugin for eclipse is Hibernate Tools, are there any alternatives out there?

Comment: I can't believe it either. Ant seems to be a better alternative beyond anything super simple. Ugh.